# Ordering columns by Primary Key position in PostgreSQL

Tags: oracle, postgresql

I am new to PostgreSQL and was wondering if there is a table which matches Oracle's user_cons_columns table which provides a column position column similar to ***user_cons_columns.position***. Essentially, I am trying to convert the following oracle code to PostgreSQL. It attains the PK columns in order of PK definition:

## Oracle Code (Original):

```
select a.table_name tab_name,
       a.colum_name col_name, 
       a.position   col_order
from user_cons_columns a, 
     user_constraints b
where a.table_name = b.table_name
and   a.constraint_name = b.constraint_name
and   b.constraint_type = 'P'
and   a.table_name = 'some_table_name';
```

## PostgreSQL Code (Oracle Equiv):

```
/* Below is my attempt at the PostgreSQL conversion */
select isc.table_name       tab_name,
       isc.column_name      col_name, 
       isc.ordinal_position col_order
from pg_attribute as pga
inner join pg_class as pgc on pga.attrelid = pgc.oid
inner join pg_namespace as pgn on pgn.oid  = pgc.relnamespace
inner join information_schema.columns as isc on isc.column_name = pga.attname
      and isc.table_name = pgc.relname 
where isc.table_name = 'sometablename';
```

In my PostgreSQL conversion attempt I am missing the relationship between the constraint and its position but use the column position. Which is not the same. Is there a way to do the former? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The column numbers of a constraint and their order are stored in `pg_constraint.conkey`; for foreign keys, the corresponding numbers of the target columns are in `pg_constraint.confkey`.

The description of table columns is in `pg_attribute`; the column number is stored in `attnum`.

Comment: Thank you this helped in getting the solution i was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Below is the solution that I derived thanks to the answer from @Laurenz Albe.

```
select isc.table_name  tab_name, 
       isc.col_name    col_name, 
       pgco.conkey[1]  col_order
from pg_attribute as pga
inner join pg_class as pgc on pga.attrelid = pgc.oid
inner join pg_namespace as pgn on pgn.oid = pgc.relnamespace 
inner join information_schema.columns as isc on isc.column = pga.attname
          and isc.table_name = pgc.relname
inner join pg_constraint as pgco on pgco.conkey[1] = pga.attnum 
          and pgco.connamespace = pgc.relnamespace
          and pgco.conrelid = pga.attrelid
where isc.table_name = 'sometablename'
and pgco.contype ='p';
```

Hope this is useful to someone else.

Comment: That only works for constraints defined on a single column.

Comment: Yes, after posting and testing it against my oracle version, i'm noticing that this does not list the multiple columns on the constraint. Any suggestions on how to implement this?

Comment: Use a lateral join with `unnest(pgco.conkey)`.